# Formula to find the first Wednesday between two dates in Google sheet

Tags: date, google-sheets

I am looking for a Google Sheet formula to find the first Wednesday between two dates. The dates are for example 05-01-2023 and 11-01-2023, the first Wednesday is the 11th... example 05-01-2022 and 11-01-2022, the first Wednesday is the 5th...

So far my idea was to create a sequence of days between the two dates, e.g.

```
=sequence(days(date(2023,1,11),date(2023,1,5))+1,1,date(2023,1,5))
```

and then use this sequence as followed

```
=weekday(sequence(days(date(2023,1,11),date(2023,1,5))+1,1,date(2023,1,5)))=4
```

Where 4 is the day of the week...

Then put it all in a filter like

```
=filter(sequence(days(date(2023,1,11),date(2023,1,5))+1,1,date(2023,1,5)),weekday(sequence(days(date(2023,1,11),date(2023,1,5))+1,1,date(2023,1,5)))=4,1,1)
```

However I am getting an error: FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 7, column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

if it all worked I was thinking of having a formula like:

```
=to_date(index(filter(sequence(days(date(2023,1,11),date(2023,1,5))+1,1,date(2023,1,5)),weekday(sequence(days(date(2023,1,11),date(2023,1,5))+1,1,date(2023,1,5)))=4,1,1)))
```

Anybody can help me out?

Comment: A2+mod(2-weekday(a2,3)) from phone

Comment: @TomSharpe A2 containing what value?

Comment: The original date

Comment: What's `1,1` at the last?

Comment: @TheMaster it is to get the first occurrence

Comment: Using the MOD I am getting the wrong number of arguments error... hmm

Comment: That's right, should have been ...,7) of course (did say it was from my phone!)

Comment: Yes, but why is it in `FILTER`?

Comment: I was trying to say that you don't need a filter if your only goal is to find the _first_ Wednesday following the start date. There is a separate question of why the filter in OP's question didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I intended

```
=A2+mod(2-weekday(A2,3),7)
```

[image]

BTW your formula also works with a slight tweak

```
=filter(sequence(days(date(2023,1,11),date(2023,1,5))+1,1,date(2023,1,5)),weekday(sequence(days(date(2023,1,11),date(2023,1,5))+1,1,date(2023,1,5)))=4)
```

or

```
=to_date(filter(sequence(days(date(2023,1,11),date(2023,1,5))+1,1,date(2023,1,5)),weekday(sequence(days(date(2023,1,11),date(2023,1,5))+1,1,date(2023,1,5)))=4))
```